# Crystal Reports databaselogin promt

Tags: database, crystal-reports, authentication

im using CR version 13. With VS2010 and CR SP1 for VS2010.

I have a report with lots of subreports. They use XML schemas for data at design time and then uses runtime populated datasets. It works great on my development machine. But on other development machines or in deployment the report pops up a databaselogon promt asking for username etc.

Ive seen alot of people having similar problems, nobody have an answear. Let me make it clear, i dont use a database in any way shape or form.
Other reports works ok, only my new report do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had some subreports i wanted to supress. I did this by simply not setting any datasource on them. For some reason CR on my development machine didnt pop up a dialog for datasource, so i assumed it worked.

What i do instead now, wich is proberbly also the better way. is to give the report a parameter value wich is used in the supress formulas of the sub reports.